# What is the in-realms publishing date of Volo's Guide to Monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms

Volotham Geddarn, the infamous book writer and troublemaker, but still a human.

In his bio page, there are publishing dates for some of the other books (in the 1300DR) but not for the "latest" guide to monsters.

Is there anywhere a reference to when the book is out? It seems the 5e campaign is set in the late 1400DR so it may or may not be a century between them.

Comment: Elminster's editorial notes and comments suggest that Volo is, as an authority, not to be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

## As of right now, unknown

The guide itself doesn't have any information about this (that I can find), and even the [Forgotten Realms wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Volo), which has a list of Volo's books and publication dates, lacks one for VGtM.

If you really want an answer, I think your best bet might be to tweet at one of the designers--Mike Mearls comes to mind as someone who might have an answer.